# Splitting linked list so many times puts into stack overflow c++

Tags: c++, split, mergesort, singly-linked-list

Oh dear; I seem to have misthought this.

I would like to split a singly-linked list 10,000 times, but evidently (and I didn't know this before you guys helped me) it causes a stack overflow.

I'm really new to this, so is there any way I could still do this and not cause a stack overflow? Using references or something?

Here's the method:

```
Node* Node::Split()
{
    if(next == NULL)
    {
        return this;
    }
    Node *newNode = this->next;
    if(this->next != NULL)
    {

        this->next = newNode->next;
    }
    if(newNode->next != NULL)
    {
        newNode->next = newNode->next->Split();
    }
    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: The stack overflow is the deep recursion. Do the splitting iteratively rather than recursively, and you'll be fine.

Comment: as in a while loop around that line?

Comment: @Tomalak_Geret'kal sorry forgot to tag

Comment: @Tazzy: You'll need to change a bit more than that, but, yes, your solution will involve a loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split method for merge sort singly linked list = stack overflow C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844796/split-method-for-merge-sort-singly-linked-list-stack-overflow-c)

Comment: @Ben tis slighly except a different question relating to it because I got the answer I needed from that other one

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write this as a loop rather than a recursive call. Keep track of your position in the original list, and both ends of the new lists, and append nodes alternately to each list.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your recursion does stop at some point (try a small data set). If it does then you have no problems there and the next thing to do is ask your compiler to increase the stack size for you. The default is quite small (I think it is one megabyte on vc++ 10).